# veins/sumo "hello world" example explanation

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I have run the Veins/sumo "hello world" example successfully, now I am digging into its code so I can get some basics before writing my own scenario, the problem that I can't find where is the code responsible for creating the nodes (cars) and managing their mobility (initial position...)?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Veins default example use the SUMO flow to insert the cars in the scenario, as you can see [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/examples/veins/erlangen.rou.xml#L10), where the cars follow the route0. Start on the edge "-39539626" and goes to the edge "-5445204#2" and going on. SUMO also can work with trips and route (manually created or by randomTrips.py) and stop point, read more [here](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes)

Comment: I already saw that file (erlangen.rou.xml) but there is only vtype:
<routes>
   <vType id="vtype0" accel="2.6" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" length="2.5" minGap="2.5" maxSpeed="14" color="1,1,0"/>
   there is no explicitly defined vehicle with explicitly defined departure point just like
<vehicle id="34" depart="34.00">
        <route edges="192597251#1 -192597251#1 -192597251#0 -192597189 -192597286 -192597102 192597183#0 192597183#1 192597183#2 192597183#3 192597183#4 -192664349#0"/>
    </vehicle>

Comment: SUMO flow don't use departure tag, use begin, [read the documentation](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes#Repeated_vehicles_.28Flows.29).